# How to add if statement in arrow function

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

i'm a beginner in JS and was wondering what is the syntax of an arrow function with an if statement with a regular function such as function

```
getStringLength(string){
  let stringLength;
  if (string.length === 1){
     stringLength = `La chaîne contient qu'un seul caractère`;
  } else {
     stringLength = `La chaîne contient ${string.length} caractères`;
  }
     return stringLength;
}
```

Comment: The if block is part of the function body and does not care or change if you use an arrow function instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That would be

```
const getStringLength = (string) => {
  let stringLength;
    if (string.length === 1){
            stringLength = `La chaîne contient qu'un seul caractère`;
    } else {
            stringLength = `La chaîne contient ${string.length} caractères`;
    }
    return stringLength;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With ternary this would look like this using an arrow function.

Note that with arrow functions you can avoid using the `return` keyword

```js
  
const getStringLength = (string) => string.length === 1 ? `La chaîne contient qu'un seul caractère` : `La chaîne contient ${string.length} caractères`

console.log(getStringLength('a'))
console.log(getStringLength('abcdef'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in one line

```js
const getStringLength = (string) =>
  string.length === 1 ?
  `La chaîne contient qu'un seul caractère` :
  `La chaîne contient ${string.length} caractères`
  
  
console.log(getStringLength('a'))
console.log(getStringLength('ab'))
```

Answer (score -1):

Like this

```
const getStringLength = (string) => {
        let stringLength;
        string.length === 1 ? ( stringLength = `La chaîne contient qu'un seul caractère`) : ( stringLength = `La chaîne contient ${string.length} caractères`);
        }
        return stringLength;
    }
```